# Is there a way to write a function that using odbc::Statement in a loop?

Tags: rust

I have working example of a simple loop (mostly taken from the odbc crate's example):

```
use std::io;
use odbc::*;
use odbc_safe::AutocommitOn;
fn main(){
    let env = create_environment_v3().map_err(|e| e.unwrap()).unwrap();
    let conn = env.connect_with_connection_string(CONN_STRING).unwrap();
    let mut stmt = Statement::with_parent(&conn).unwrap();
    loop {
        let mut sql_text = String::new();
        println!("Please enter SQL statement string: ");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut sql_text).unwrap();
        stmt = match stmt.exec_direct(&sql_text).unwrap() {
            Data(mut stmt) => {
                let cols = stmt.num_result_cols().unwrap();
                while let Some(mut cursor) = stmt.fetch().unwrap() {
                    for i in 1..(cols + 1) {
                        match cursor.get_data::<&str>(i as u16).unwrap() {
                            Some(val) => print!(" {}", val),
                            None => print!(" NULL"),
                        }
                    }
                    println!();
                }
                stmt.close_cursor().unwrap()
            }
            NoData(stmt) => {println!("Query executed, no data returned"); stmt}
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to create new Statements for each query, as I just can .close_cursor().
I'd like to extract the loop's body to a function, like this:

```
fn exec_stmt(stmt: Statement<Allocated, NoResult, AutocommitOn>) {
    //loop's body here
}
```

But I just can't! The .exec_direct() method mutably consumes my Statement and returns another. I tried different ways to pass Statement arg to the function (borrow, RefCell, etc), but they all fail when using in a loop. I am still new to Rust, so most likely I just don't know something, or does the .exec_direct's Statement consumption makes it impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no nice way to move and then move back values through parameters. It's probably best to copy what `.exec_direct` does and just make the return type of your function a statement as well.

The usage would then look like this:

```rust
let mut stmt = Statement::with_parent(&conn).unwrap();
loop {
    stmt = exec_stmt(stmnt);
}
```

and your function signature would be:

```rust
fn exec_stmt(stmt: Statement<...>) -> Statement<...> {
  match stmt.exec_direct() {
    ...
  }
}
```

---

I probably wouldn't recommend this, but if you really wanted to get it to work you could use `Option` and the `.take()` method.

```
fn exec_stmt(some_stmt: &mut Option<Statement<...>>) {
   let stmt = some_stmt.take().unwrap();
   // do stuff ...
   some_stmt.replace(stmt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [odbc-safe](https://crates.io/crates/odbc-api) crate tried to have each state transition of ODBC reflected in a different type. The [odbc-api](https://crates.io/crates/odbc-api) crate also tries to protect you from errors, but is a bit more subtle about it. Your use case would be covered by the the `Preallocated` struct.

The analog example from the [odbc-api documentation](https://docs.rs/odbc-api/0.16.0/odbc_api/struct.Preallocated.html) looks like this:

```rust
use odbc_api::{Connection, Error};
use std::io::{self, stdin, Read};

fn interactive(conn: &Connection) -> io::Result<()>{
    let mut statement = conn.preallocate().unwrap();
    let mut query = String::new();
    stdin().read_line(&mut query)?;
    while !query.is_empty() {
        match statement.execute(&query, ()) {
            Err(e) => println!("{}", e),
            Ok(None) => println!("No results set generated."),
            Ok(Some(cursor)) => {
                // ...print cursor contents...
            },
        }
        stdin().read_line(&mut query)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

This will allow you to declare a function without any trouble:

```rust
use odbc_api::Preallocated;

fn exec_statement(stmt: &mut Preallocated) {
    // loops body here
}
```